# Not able to set postgres 9.6 DB parameters for Amazon RDS Aurora

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

My AWS RDS Aurora PostgreSQL instance is up and running with basic configurations. While creating an instance it showed "DB parameter group" setting (grayed) and defaulted to "default.aurora-postgresql9.6".

So, I tried to find and modify below postgres DB parameter's values for `default.aurora-postgresql9.6` (under Parameter Group).

```
wal_level=minimal; 
fsync=off; 
synchronous_commit=off;
"ALTER SYSTEM" privilege for postgres
```

Also, tried to change the parameter's values after connecting to Aurora instance. But, it requires DB superuser access. AWS RDS/Aurora doesn't allow creation of DB superuser ([Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.html)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change the default parameter group. You can create a new parameters group and change the DB instance to use the new parameter group.

1. Create a new parameter group. This will be based upon the default parameter group.
2. Modify the parameter group as you require.
3. Modify the DB instance to use the new parameter group.
4. Reboot the DB instance.

The following article will help you with the details:

[Working with DB Parameter Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.html)

Comment: Thanks John . We found fsyn parameter, however throws error on modification. (Error saving: The parameter fsync cannot be modified. (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request ID: 9b0c633e-b7cc-496c-91a2-c68d9f897680))                                                                                        "wal_level=minimal" parameter not found.

Comment: This link covers why you cannot disable fsync. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_BestPractices.html

Comment: Okay, got what you are saying. To my 2nd question on wal_level=minimal, I found AWS doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html for the same. It stats how to modify "logical "value, but we are looking for modification of wal_level to "minimal".

Comment: Amazon limits what you can do with RDS at the administration level. Remember RDS is a service with SLAs so Amazon does not want you changing things that can affect HA or DR.

Comment: Thank you John. It helped. I did posted same question to AWS forum and got repose, check this https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=271756.